Showing that $\langle A \rangle$ can be equivalently defined via $F(A)$ and via $F^{ab}(A)$ when $G$ is abelian, $A \subset G$.
In Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0 the author introduces the subgroup generated by a subset as follows (paraphrased):

Let $G$ be a group, and $A \subset G$ any subset. By the universal property of free groups there is a unique group homomorphism
$$\varphi: F(A) \to G$$
extending this inclusion. The image of this homomorphism is a subgroup of $G$, the subgroup generated by $A$ in $G$, often denoted $\langle A \rangle$.

He then states the following:

Of course, if $G$ is abelian, then $\varphi$ factors through $F^{ab}(A)$, so we may replace $F(A)$ by $F^{ab}(A)$ in this case.

While this seems plausible enough, I would like to verify it rigorously, and this is where I am a bit stuck at the moment. I would prefer to do it without invoking any concrete construction of free groups. The following is my attempt so far.
Let $j: A \to F(A)$ and $k: A \to F^{ab}(A)$ be the set-functions associated with the universal properties of $F(A)$ and $F^{ab}(A)$, respectively, and let $i: A \to G$ be the inclusion map. Then $\varphi$ is the unique homomorphism such that $\varphi \circ j = i$. There is also a unique homomorphism $\psi: F^{ab}(A) \to G$ such that $\psi \circ k = i$, and a unique homomorphism $\chi: F(A) \to F^{ab}(A)$ such that $\chi \circ j = k$. This all follows from universal properties.
To verify the authors statement, we must show that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ have the same image. It follows from the above that $i = \psi \circ \chi \circ j$, and hence that $\psi \circ \chi = \varphi$ (by the uniqueness property of $\varphi$). Thus
$$\varphi(F(A)) \subset \psi(F^{ab}(A)).$$
But how do I show the reverse inclusion? I suppose showing that $\chi$ is surjective would do the trick, but I have not been able to.

Yes showing that $\chi$ is surjective would do the trick. Where did you get stuck here? It is just about using the universal properties of these groups.

@user1729 I am stuck at trying to show that $\psi(F^{ab}(A)) \subset \varphi(F(A))$, for example by showing that $\chi$ is surjective. And yes, I would prefer to use universal properties rather than any explicit construction of the free groups.

@user1729 Though, if there is a nice argument using explicit constructions I suppose that would be fine too, since it should be possible to extend it to the general case by using the result that initial objects are isomorphic.

My question was: where did you get stuck showing surjectivity of $\chi$?

@user1729 Sorry. I didn't really get anywhere at all with showing that $\chi$ is surjective. I tried to find something using the universal properties of $F(A)$ and $F^{ab}(A)$, but I did not find anything promising.

Did you draw the commutative diagram corresponding to the universal property of $F(A)$, where $A$ is the set and $F^{ab}(A)$ is the other group?

Yes, I did, and of course $\chi$ is the unique homomorphism that makes that diagram (which also involves $j$ and $k$) commute. But I don't see how to conclude surjectivity of $\chi$ from that diagram, since $k$ is not surjective in general.

No, $k$ is not surjective. It is just a map. The point is that $k(A)$ generates $F^{ab}(A)$. Commutativity of the diagram gives is that $k(A)=\chi j(A)$, and so the image of the homomorphism $\chi$ contains a generating set for $F^{ab}(A)$, and so contains all of $F^{ab}(A)$.

@user1729 I see. It seems like you have the same argument in mind as Arturo wrote in his very nice answer, which he unfortunately removed. (It seems he took my follow up questions as criticism, which was not at all my intention. I just wanted to understand some details better.) Seems like this is the way to go; I might try to fill in the details myself, or you can write a full answer if you want.

I can see Arturo's answer (as have enough rep), but it makes me wonder how much detail you are after. The main detail to clarify, I believe, is that $k(A)$ generates $F^{ab}(A)$. Possibly you could try filling in the details yourself, and then post this as an answer?

@user1729 Yes, I think that was the only part that was unclear to me. I will try to work it out myself, but I am not sure I will be able to recreate the rest of Arturo's answer. I also have another idea based on the explicit realizations of the free groups. The tricky part is to generalize it to arbitrary realizations. But I think I have worked out how to do that with the result that initial objects are isomorphic.

Here is a proof that $\chi$ is surjective that only requires the universal properties of the free and free abelian groups, and the notion of quotient of an abelian group.
Following the given notation: $(F(A),j)$ is a free group on $A$, with $j\colon A\to F(A)$ the structure function. $(F^{\rm ab}(A),k)$ is a free abelian group on $A$, with $k\colon A\to F^{\rm ab}(A)$ the structure function. The map $k\colon A\to F^{\rm ab}(A)$ induces the morphism $\chi\colon F(A)\to F^{\rm ab}(A)$, which is the unique morphism such that $\chi\circ j = k$.
Now consider the abelian group $N = F^{\rm ab}(A)/\chi(F(A))$; we can do the quotient because (i) $\chi$ is a homomorphism, so $\chi(F(A))$ is a subgroup of $F^{\rm ab}(A)$; and (ii) $F^{\rm ab}(A)$ is abelian, so all subgroups are normal. Moreover, because the quotient of an abelian group is abelian, $N$ is abelian.
Let $\pi\colon F^{\rm ab}(A) \to N$ be the canonical morphism onto the quotient, and let $\zeta\colon F^{\rm ab}(A)\to N$ be the map sending everything to the identity. I claim that $\pi\circ k = \zeta\circ k$ as functions from $A$ to $N$. Indeed, we have that for all $a\in A$,
$$k(a) = \chi\circ j(a)  = \chi(j(a))\subseteq \chi(j(A))\subseteq \chi(F(A)),$$
so $\pi(k(a)) = k(a)\chi(F(A)) = e\chi(F(A))$, the identity element of $N$. On the other hand, $\zeta\circ k(a) = e\chi(F(A))$ because everything in $F^{\rm ab}(A)$ is mapped to the identity under $\zeta$. Thus, $\pi\circ k$ and $\zeta\circ k$ have the same domain (namely $A$), same codomain, and same value at each element of $A$, so they are equal.
The universal property of $F^{\rm ab}(A)$ states that given any function $g\colon A\to N$, there exists a unique morphism $\eta\colon F^{\rm ab}(A)\to N$ such that $g = \eta\circ k$. Taking $g=\zeta\circ k$, we see that $\eta=\zeta$ is such a mophism; but we just saw that $\zeta\circ k = \pi\circ k$, so $\pi$ also works. (Alternatively, the same argument using $\pi\circ k$ shows $\pi$ works, and the fact that $\zeta\circ k = \pi\circ k$ shows they both work for the same function.)
By the uniqueness clause of the universal property, we conclude that $\pi=\zeta$. But that means that the canonical map onto the quotient $F^{\rm ab}(A) \to F^{\rm ab}(A)/\chi(F(A))$ is the same as the zero map. That means that $\chi(F(A))=F^{\rm ab}(A)$, proving that $\chi$ is surjective, as desired.

Beautiful! Thank you fo taking the time to answer again Arturo. I am sorry if my questions on your previous answer came across as impertinent. They were not meant as a critique; I just had a hard time grasping a certain step of the proof.

The universal property of Abelianisation tells you immediately $\varphi$ would factor through $(F(A))^{ab}$; it is an easy theorem (left adjoints compose, really) that this is isomorphic with $F^{ab}(A)$.
Let $\chi:H\to H^{ab}$ be the Abelianisation homomorphism; you care for the case $H=F(A)$, and you want $\chi$ to be surjective because this would entail the image of $\varphi$ is the image of $F^{ab}(A)\to G$, so the replacement is genuine.
But $\chi$ is an epimorphism in the category of groups! Indeed, the uniqueness part of the universal property tells you immediately that if $f\chi=g\chi=:h$, then $f,g$ are two factorisations of $h$ through $\chi$ and must, thus, be equal.
So the only bit of concrete group theory we need, rather than category theory, is the fact that every epimorphism of groups is set-theoretically surjective. This is answered very nicely here.

Thank you for answering! The answer goes a bit beyond my knowledge level so far (I have not yet encountered abelianisation, nor the prerequisite of quotient groups and commutators) but I appreciate it nonetheless. Unless a more elementary answer appears, I will accept your answer.

@ummg Ah… I didn’t know that you didn’t know about Abelianisation. Since you were talking about unique factorisation through $F^{ab}(A)$ when $G$ is Abelian, which is exactly the Abelianisation property,… but ok: as long as you can convince yourself $\varphi$ is unique in general, you will know that $F(A)\to F^{ab}(A)$ is an epimorphism

For sure, a more elementary method will arise if you use explicit calculations. It is clear from the construction that $F(A)\to F^{ab}(A)$ surjects. I just used an “abstract nonsense” argument since it seemed you wanted one :-) Abelianisation is cool to know about. If you don’t follow the construction, it is enough to know that Abelianisation exists.

Showing that an epimorphism into an abelian group must be surjective is easier than proving the general case that epimorphisms in $\mathsf{Group}$ are surjective, because you can use the cokernel.

@ArturoMagidin Of course! I see you’ve mentioned that

For whatever it's worth, here follows an argument for the surjectivity of $\chi$ based on the "concrete" constructions of $F(A)$ and $F_{ab}(A)$ given in Aluffi's book.
In the text $F(A)$ is realized as the set of reduced words on $A$, with multiplication defined as juxtaposition followed by reduction, while $F_{ab}(A)$ is realized as $\mathbb Z^{\oplus A}$. (See the book for details, such as how $j$ and $k$ are defined). It is straightforward to design a surjective homomorphism $\chi: F(A) \to F_{ab}(A)$ such that $\chi \circ j = k$. Essentially, let $\chi$ count the number of occurences of each symbol in a word, with "inverse" symbols counted negative.
It remains only to show that this result generalizes to arbitrary realizations of the free groups. Hence let $(j', F'(A))$ and $(k', F'_{ab}(A))$ be some alternate realizations, with induced homomorphism $\chi': F'(A) \to F'_{ab}(A)$ such that $\chi' \circ j' = k'$. We will show that $\chi'$ is surjective too.
Now, $(j, F(A))$ and $(j', F'(A))$ are both initial objects in the category used to define free groups on $A$ (see Aluffi's text for details). Hence they are isomorphic as objects (Proposition 5.4 in the book). Carefully parsing what this means in the present category, we find that the induced homomorphism $\sigma: F'(A) \to F(A)$ is an isomorphism. Similarly, the induced homomorphism $\tau: F'_{ab}(A) \to F_{ab}(A)$ is an isomorphism.
Note that
$$k = \tau \circ k' = \tau \circ \chi' \circ j' = \tau \circ \chi' \circ \sigma^{-1} \circ j.$$
By the uniqueness property of $\chi$ we have $\tau \circ \chi' \circ \sigma^{-1} = \chi$, or
$$\chi ' = \tau^{-1} \circ \chi \circ \sigma.$$
The right-hand side is a composition of surjective maps, thus $\chi'$ is surjective.

Here is a completely different argument. It is based on an alternative characterization of the subgroup of $G$ generated by $A$, namely as the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $A$.
Lemma: Let $F(A)$ be (any realization of) the free group on $A$ and let $j: A \to F(A)$ be the associated map. Moreover, let $i$ be the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow G$ and let $\varphi: F(A) \to G$ be the unique homomorphism such that $\varphi \circ j = i$. Then the image of $\varphi$ is the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $H$.
Proof: Let $I$ be the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $H$. It is clear that $I \subset \operatorname{im} \varphi$, since $\operatorname{im} \varphi$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $A$. To prove the reverse inclusion, let $H$ be an arbitrary subgroup of $G$ containing $A$. Let $\psi: F(A) \to H$ be the unique homomorphism such that $\psi \circ j = i'$, where $i': A \hookrightarrow H$. Denoting the inclusion $H \hookrightarrow G$ by $i''$, we have
$$i = i'' \circ i' = i'' \circ \psi \circ j,$$
and thus $i'' \circ \psi = \varphi$, by the uniqueness property of $\varphi$. It follows that
$$\operatorname{im} \varphi = \operatorname{im} \psi \subset H.$$
Since $H$ was arbitrary we have $\operatorname{im} \varphi \subset I$, which completes the proof.
Corollary: Aluffi's definition of $\langle A \rangle$ does not depend on which realization of $F(A)$ is used.
Finally, when $G$ is abelian, we can replace $F(A)$ by $F^{ab}(A)$ in the above lemma; every step of the proof still works. Hence the definitions of $\langle A \rangle$ via $F(A)$, via $F^{ab}(A)$, and as the intersection of all subgroups containing $A$, are all equivalent.

Looks ok to me ${}{}$

@FShrike Thank you for reading it; I'm very happy with how simple it turned out. I sort of stumbled upon it since I wanted to show that the definition via $F(A)$ was equivalent to the definition via intersection anyway. Only afterwards did I realize that it provides a solution to my question here.
